# How to run Pylama only for uncommitted changes (git)

Tags: git, commit, pylama

I have been looking to run python linter only for uncommitted changes and not my entire project, Is there a way to run Pylama only for git changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a list of the uncommitted changes to Pylama as a parameter.

Run from the command line:

```
pylama "$(git --no-pager diff --name-only)"
```